# ReactJS/Javascript: componentDidMount() and render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

[image]The console log inside the render function shows data.  The `console.log(this.props)` for the `componentDidMount()` is undefined (huh???).  How is that possible? I'm not understanding how `async` work in React.

```
class Graph extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {  startTime:this.props.startTime, 
                    endTime:this.props.endTime,
                    nodes:this.props.data
                  }
    //console.log('graph data:', this.props.data)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
   // console.log('nodes:', this.props.data)
    this.force = d3.forceSimulation(this.state.nodes)
      .force("charge",
        d3.forceManyBody()
          .strength(this.props.forceStrength)
      )
      .force("x", d3.forceX(this.props.width / 2))
      .force("y", d3.forceY(this.props.height / 2));

    this.force.on('tick', () => this.setState({data: this.props.data}));
    console.log('setState:', this.props.data)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.force.stop();
  }

  render() {
   // console.log('graph datas:', this.props.data)
    return (

      <svg width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height}>
      {console.log('map data:', this.props.data)}
      {Object.keys(this.props.data).map((node, index) =>(
     <circle r={node.r} cx={node.x} cy={node.y} fill="red" key={index}/>
      ))}
      </svg>
    );
  }//render
}//Component

export default graphql(getObjectsQuery, 
  { options: (ownProps) => { 
    console.log(ownProps.startTime); 
    return ({ second: { startTime: ownProps.startTime,
                            endTime: ownProps.endTime
     } }) 
  } } )(Graph);
```

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount` hook is synchronously called when the component is mounted. It isn't called on re-render.

As [the reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) states:

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

`this.props.data` isn't defined at this moment.

While `render` hook is triggered on each re-render. The question doesn't show how the component is used but it's expected that `data` value in `<Graph data={...}` becomes defined asynchronously, and `console.log(this.props.data)` in `render` reflects that.

Comment: I am having a hard time with the syntax can you provide an example with the D3 code I have above. I am very new to React and D3.

Comment: I posted the entire component in the original question.

Comment: I won't be able to make it work because it's only a part of something bigger. This is what https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is about. How is `graphql(..)` export being used? What exactly is the problem with the syntax? This is basically what's going on in your case, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fsv6iu . Notice that `data` will be initially undefined in `render`, too.

Comment: Do you need the other component?

Comment: The graphql export binds the query to component component.  Once the results from the query comes back it can be accessed through props.

Comment: Can you please atleast take a look at Graph and let me know if the logic and syntax is correct?

Comment: Possibly yes. I'm still not sure what example you are looking for. You already have working example at hand, don't you? The code you posted seems ok to me, and the behaviour you described is expected. I updated https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fsv6iu , notice that if you need to put some logic that needs to keep an eye on `this.props.data`, you need to put it into both `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: In my my code it looks like componentDiDMount is undefined and I do not have a componentDidUpdate. Can we start there?

Comment: Its so frustrating to see the data in the console starring at you and not be able to print it to the screen.

Comment: You have `componentDidMount` in your code. You may not need `componentDidUpdate`, this depends on what you're trying to do. What exactly is the problem with printing it to the screen? If this is all about debugging, you can print `this.props`, it will update dynamically in console, at least in Chrome.

Comment: The program complies fine and the submit button shift down after I click the submit button but the screen is blank.

Comment: Is componentDidUpdate syntax right? Is it doing what it is suppose to do?

Comment: I want to print the results from the query, which is being stored in data onto the screen.

Comment: You can see it working in Stackblitz link above . See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate . Yes, it seems to be a proper place to do that, *print the results from the query*. You could do this in `render` too but it's not advised to put anything but presentation there.

Comment: `{action: "Changed", timestamp: 14993480500, object: Array(1), Second: Array(1), __typename: "action", …}`

Comment: @etus I added a screenshot to the original question.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly the problem is. Is it *The program complies fine and the submit button shift down after I click the submit button but the screen is blank*? This differs a lot from your original question and certainly requires https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that reflects your current case, preferably a workable demo, because it needs to be debugged.

Comment: I'm using a neo4j data base so it will be difficult to set up a demo.

Comment: Do you have time to help me with trying to graph something else?

Comment: I don't use GraphQL. You can check https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/mocking.html

Comment: So I was able to figure out how to access the data. I am now trying to figure out how to render the graph.